# Java Parallel Invocation for 3rd party system

Tags: java, spring

I have to invoke a third party API 5 times with different params and produce a single output to my caller.
Sequential way is fine but it takes time as each call takes 2 seconds as result 10 seconds. If I can invoke parallel I can produce the output in 3 seconds. What is the best way to achieve in spring, java environment?

Comment: Well we'd likely need to know what api you are actually calling.  Is it thread safe, for example?  Please show your code so we know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there a a lot of approaches you can try ...
The easiest might be:

Annotate your method that makes the API call with `@Async` and enable the async execution in your spring app by adding `@EnableAsync` in your configuration. Now you can just call your method 5 times and they will be executed in parallel. You can find an example here https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Or create your own thread pool e.g.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
pool.submit(() -> myApiCallMethod());
```